# Changing databases in PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, connection

The following PL/SQL code attempts to connect to an Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 database, execute a command and repeat the connection and command for three other databases of the same Oracle version. The code is:

```
DECLARE
    PASSWORD VARCHAR2(20);
    PASS_WORD VARCHAR2(20);
    ENVIRONMENT CHAR(1) := 'T';
    USERID INTEGER(10);
    USER_ID_4_ACCTS_TO_BE_DELETED INTEGER(10);
    TYPE ARRAY_T IS VARRAY(4) OF VARCHAR2(4);
    ARRAY ARRAY_T := ARRAY_T('A','BB','CCC','DDDD'');
BEGIN
    USERID := &USER_ID; -- Get user's id from keyboard (assume no change)
    PASSWORD := &PASS_WORD; -- Get user's password from keyboard (assume no change)
    FOR i IN 1..ARRAY.COUNT LOOP
        CONNECT ARRAY(i) || '_UPDADM_' || USERID || '/' || PASSWORD || '.' || '@CM_CM' || ENVIRONMENT || ARRAY(i)
        CALL ADMIN_USERS.DROP_USER(USERID ,'UPDADM');
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

The first connection string would look like:
    CONNECT A_UPDADM_123456/Password.@CM_CMTA

The following error is thrown.

```
CONNECT ARRAY(i) || '_UPDADM_' || USERID || '/' || PASSWORD || '.' || '@CM_CM' || ENVIRONMENT || ARRAY(i)

*
ERROR at line 13:
ORA-06550: line 13, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CONNECT" when expecting one of the
following:
( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null
pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

Comment: Where in the PL/SQL manual did you find `CONNECT` ?

Comment: Connect to the desired database using SQL*Plus which can be easily scripted and run this PL/SQL code in that session.

Comment: Also, having two variables in the same scope named `password` and `pass_word` is the kind of thing that causes confusion and errors in production code. However, `pass_word` is not used after it's declared. (`&pass_word` is something different again.)

Comment: Also, not only is there no `connect` keyword, there's no `call` either.

Comment: @ramana_k Very helpful, you should repost as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reconnect to a different database within PL/SQL. The connected database instance provides the runtime environment, so changing it would be like a shell script logging into a different server mid-script, or a running Java process dynamically handing itself over to a different JVM.

[Switch user in pl/sql code block in sqlplus sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654856/switch-user-in-pl-sql-code-block-in-sqlplus-sessions)

[AskTOM: How to change user dynamically](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:12167997944197::NO:::)

In 12c the [Multitenant](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/multitenant-part1-pdbs-2193987.html) option may give you some more options, but this would still be similar to a DBA script acting on multiple users within the same database rather than making completely new connections mid-procedure.